# HTML5 canvas color and JS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a project where i am trying to only use plain JS without any libraries. This project is about some HTML5 canvas, and the idea is:

1. There is a colorpicker, but if it is not set yet, the stroke should have rainbow-colors. Else it should have the color of the colorpicker.
2. The stroke thickness varies constantly, but when it becomes over 100 it starts decreasing and when it becomes under 2 it starts increasing.

But i can't really seem to get the color in set or unset condition

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML5 Canvas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="base" type="color" name="base" value="#ffc600">
    <canvas id="draw" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
    <script>
const canvas = document.querySelector('#draw');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#BADA55';
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = 100;

let isDrawing = false;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;
let hue = 0;
let direction = true;


const colorpicker = document.querySelector('input');
colorpicker.addEventListener('change', () => {
// This weird if-statement checks if the color of the colorpicker is not set
  if (typeof this.value !== 'undefined') {
    rainbow = false;
    color = this.value;
  } else {
    rainbow = true;
  }
});



function draw(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return; // stop the fn from running when they are not moused down
  console.log(e);
  hue ++;
  if (hue >= 360) {
    hue = 0;
  }
  if (rainbow === true) {
    color = `hsl(${hue}, 50%, 100%)`;
  } else {
    rainbow = false;
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();

  // start from
  ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
  // go to
  ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  ctx.stroke();
  // getting our new offset
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];

  // if linewidth becomes over 100 it will start decreasing 
  // and if it becomes lesser than 2 it will start increasing
  if (ctx.lineWidth >= 100 || ctx.lineWidth <= 2) {
    direction = !direction;
  }

  if(direction) {
    ctx.lineWidth += 2;
  } else {
    ctx.lineWidth -= 2;
  }

}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDrawing = true;
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
});


canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isDrawing = false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', () => isDrawing = false);

  </script>

  <style>
  html, body {
    margin:0;
  }
  </style>

  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone that can see what is wrong with my code or have an idea on how to do it, please help!

Comment: Please give a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Observation 1**: when you are using arrow functions you can not use `this` anymore. So is `if (typeof colorpicker.value !== 'undefined')`instead of `if (typeof this.value !== 'undefined')`

**Observation 2**: you need to declare `color` and `rainbow` as globals. Also, in the beginning `rainbow` should be `true` since the user didn't choose a color, and in your HTML you should remove the input value, otherwise the value is defined.

**Observation 3** You have color = `hsl(${hue}, 50%, 100%)`; This will always give you white since the lightness is 100%; you will need color = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#draw');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
//ctx.strokeStyle = '#BADA55';
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.lineWidth = 100;

let isDrawing = false;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;
let hue = 0;
let direction = true;
let rainbow = true;
let color;


const colorpicker = document.querySelector('input');
colorpicker.addEventListener('change', () => {
  //console.log(typeof colorpicker.value);
// This weird if-statement checks if the color of the colorpicker is not set
  if (typeof colorpicker.value !== 'undefined') {
    rainbow = false;
    color = colorpicker.value;
  } else {
    rainbow = true;
  }
  
  //console.log(rainbow);
});



function draw(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return; // stop the fn from running when they are not moused down
  //console.log(e);
 
  
 
  if (rainbow === true) {
    color = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
     hue ++;
     if (hue >= 360) {
     hue = 0;
  }
  } else {
    rainbow = false;

  }
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();

  // start from
  ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
  // go to
  ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  ctx.stroke();
  // getting our new offset
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];

  // if linewidth becomes over 100 it will start decreasing 
  // and if it becomes lesser than 2 it will start increasing
  if (ctx.lineWidth >= 100 || ctx.lineWidth <= 2) {
    direction = !direction;
  }

  if(direction) {
    ctx.lineWidth += 2;
  } else {
    ctx.lineWidth -= 2;
  }

}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDrawing = true;
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
});


canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isDrawing = false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', () => isDrawing = false);
```

```html
<input id="base" type="color" name="base" >
<canvas id="draw" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```